# Job execution fails when parallelism is increased beyond 1

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm submitting a Flink job to a cluster that has three Task Managers via the Flink dashboard. When I set `Parallelism` to 1 (which is default), everything runs as expected. But when I increase `Parallelism` to anything more than 1, the job fails with the exception,

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/flink-io-f91d7812-a411-4b58-a891-c9be1cde91da/08caeac37d6b8351daf6a3eb123a473106c56381b101f3e5d9704df9f78406a2.0.buffer (No such file or directory)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.BufferSpiller.createSpillingChannel(BufferSpiller.java:259)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.BufferSpiller.<init>(BufferSpiller.java:120)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.BarrierBuffer.<init>(BarrierBuffer.java:149)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamInputProcessor.<init>(StreamInputProcessor.java:129)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OneInputStreamTask.init(OneInputStreamTask.java:56)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:235)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:718)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've enabled checkpoints on my Flink job with "Exactly Once" retry strategy every 10 seconds. Here's my checkpoint configuration,

```
env.setStateBackend(new RocksDBStateBackend(props.getFlinkCheckpointDataUri(), true));
env.enableCheckpointing(10000, EXACTLY_ONCE); //10 seconds
CheckpointConfig config = env.getCheckpointConfig();
config.enableExternalizedCheckpoints(CheckpointConfig.ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION);
```

Should I configure something else other than simply entering `2` while submitting the job in the dashboard?

If I disable checkpoints and upload the job, it runs without any error.

Comment: Just a heads up. I haven't found the root cause for this issue yet but 
restarting all the nodes has solved this issue, for now.